# Path issue in ajax ,in a wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress site

for ex,  www.test.com

There is a js file (forms.js)in the script folder of mytheme folder.

**ie (theme/mytheme/script/forms.js)**

There is a *mail.php* page in mytheme folder

**ie (theme/mytheme/mail.php)**

Following is the content of forms.js

```
function submitFormToEmail()
{

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        //document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert("Form received, thank you!");
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/mail.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I will call "submitFormToEmail",if we click a image in the page   ***www.test.com/hello_test***

Where "hello_test" page  lies in theme/mytheme/.

But the mail.php is not working.

Let me know ,how can we set the path of mail.php in the function "submitFormToEmail", so that it will work

Comment: Your indentation style is truly horrible.

Comment: what you mean, my question is not clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `/mail.php` will look for the mail.php file at `http://www.test.com/mail.php`. Just fix the path?

Either directly code the correct path into the javascript file or use php to dynamically get it using [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo#Template_Directory). There are several ways to do this, but probably the best way is to create a hidden element on the page that contains the url and then fetch this when building your ajax request. Otherwise you'd have to set php to parse js files and include it in there. Doesn't seem like a good way to me though.

```
get_bloginfo('template_url');
```

Comment: @mrtsherman  you mean give the full path like http://www.test.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/mail.php